# How to derive tangential divergence (and thus Laplace-Beltrami operator) from tangential gradient?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, field-theory, manifolds

If we define the tangential gradient for some appropriate function $f$ on a hypersurface $\Gamma$
\begin{align}
\nabla_\Gamma f = P \nabla f = (I - n n^T)\nabla f, 
\end{align}
then **we can derive** its tangential divergence
\begin{align}
\text{div}_\Gamma f = \nabla_\Gamma^T f = \nabla^T(f - n^T f n) = \mathrm{tr}(\nabla_\Gamma f)
\end{align}
and thus the Laplace-Beltrami operator
\begin{align}
\Delta_\Gamma f = \text{div}_\Gamma(\nabla_\Gamma f)
\end{align}

A lecture note says **we can derive** but doesn't say **how to derive**. 
Can you show me step by step why it holds true?

In addition, for some $g \in C^1$ the tangential divergence satisfies
\begin{align}
\text{div}_\Gamma (gf) = g \, \text{div}_\Gamma f. 
\end{align}
Why?

Comment: Are you sure $\text{div}_\Gamma f = \mathrm{tr}(\nabla_\Gamma f)$ ? Your definition of tangential gradient implies that $\nabla_\Gamma f$ is a vector, how can you take the trace of a vector?